# React Native - Build Release Failed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build a release apk for android

using

```
 gradlew assembleRelease
```

Output

```
\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\51d2ebde8fc2c987e41e4e8d648ee1a8\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
```

build.gradle

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
```

package.json

```
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, try downgrading to React 0.55, 0.54.